# SharedPreferences write in fragment and read in activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm having a little problem with `SharedPreferences`.

I'm using a Tabbed Activity, with some fragments inside. I have a `ListView` inside it and I want to get the ID of the `selectedItem`.

I'm getting an error and can't find out what it is.

I write in my SharedPreferences on a `Fragment`:

```
listViewCours.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            long itemid= listViewCours.getItemIdAtPosition(i);

            String a = String.valueOf(itemid);

            editor.putString("ItemId",a);
            editor.commit();

        }

    });
```

Then I'm trying to read it from an `Activity` :

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String cours = prefs.getString("ItemId","");
    int cours_id = Integer.parseInt(cours);
```

I don't know how to do it, but for the moment, I'm not able to get that ID in the other activity...

Comment: Make it uniform , if you use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` then use it across.

Comment: This  `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and  `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` Both must be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different types of Preferences. **MODE_PRIVATE** and **Default Shared Preference**. That's why you are getting **NULL POINTER ERROR**. Just try out the below code:

Use this in listItem:

```
listViewCours.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        long itemid= listViewCours.getItemIdAtPosition(i);

        String a = String.valueOf(itemid);

        prefs.edit().putString("ItemId",a).apply();


    }

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set value:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = preferences.edit();

    long itemid= listViewCours.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
    String a = String.valueOf(itemid);
    prefsEditor.putString("ItemId", a);
```

get value in activity:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences =  getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String ItemId=preferences.getString("ItemId", "");
```